# pandoc --metadata-file yaml on xelatex and debian - how to debug?

Tags: pandoc, metadata, def

Please guidance and help.

How can I debug a pdf generation from a latex template (using xelatex)? I am having trouble bringing metadata from yaml files, is there a way to see log, aux, out files when the pdf is generated? Or intermediate files?

I fear the new environment I am running this is not good enough be it for the python install or for packages, and I don't know how to check these.

---

I migrated from a debian test to a debian-11 (yes, the newer machine has an older version of debian). On the old machine I was able to generate a pdf from a tex template using xelatex, and now it is not working anymore.

I do "import" three yaml files with `--metadata-file`, and I use the data from the yamls. But now, these fields are not rendering anymore.

I am sorry I am not good at latex.

I use the imported data in loops using `$ for( field ) $`, where `field` is present in the yaml. And I also use: `\newcommand{\field}{ $ field $ }`; and `\def\field#1{\def\@field{#1}}` when I use fields outside of loops.

This was also asked on:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/discussions/9550

I suspect the problem is that I might not have installed some package. Here follows what I have on the new debian-11 machine.

- texlive-base
- texlive-fonts-extra
- texlive
- fonts-texgyre
- fonts-mathjax
- texlive-xetex
- texlive-publishers
- texlive-plain-generic
- texlive-pictures
- texlive-latex-recommended
- texlive-latex-extra
- texlive-latex-base
- texlive-fonts-recommended
- texlive-binaries
- python3-pygments
- python3-jinja2
- python3-docutils
- preview-latex-style
- pandoc-data
- pandoc
- libgtksourceview-4-common
- ispell
- dvisvgm
- docutils-common
- cm-super
- cm-super-minimal
- wget

Comment: You say, you are importing yaml files**s** (plural), have you tested, if it works with one file? There are issues merging multiple metadata files, i.e. later files overriding earlier ones. Also, please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: Thank you. Yes. That's not the issue. And I need a way to debug as in latex there's always something that goes wrong, unfortunately. When I fix the import, I get other errors and I should not. I fear the new environment does not do python and packages the same way somehow.

Comment: Sorry, your question is very vague which makes it hard to answer. Where does python come in all the sudden? Make a very brief but complete example that exibits the issue and we can talk. In general, if you want to debug pandoc to latex issues, do generate latex code (instead of pdf) and run {pdf,lus,xe}latex manually, that way you get slightly more expressive error messages _and_ do inspect the generated latex code

Comment: Because of the `pandoc` tag and `pandoc` in the title I guess you are converting from something to PDF via LaTeX using `pandoc`. In this case you can instead first convert to LaTeX and then run XeLaTeX to this document. Now, you can inspect the `log`, `aux` etc. files of this process (and also inspect, minimize and show the generated `tex` file to make your question clear). BTW: If it is not a LaTeX but a `pandoc` (or YAML) problem, the question is off-topic.

Comment: At least Quarto markdown  offers several `keep-*` options in the header to keep intermediary files, including  `keep-tex: true`  (in Rmarkdown  is `keep_tex: yes`) and  also  `latex-clean: false` (not in Rmarkdown, afaik).